# Installation of the Synaptics SDK

Tags: c#, sdk, synaptics-touchpad

So, I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16442480/synaptics-touchpad-signature) question on using the Synaptics SDK, but the SDK seems to have disappeared off the face of the earth, and there is barley any info about the SDK still available. Here is a link of where the sdk is suppost to be: [sdk](http://www.synaptics.com/sites/default/files/SynCOMAPIv1_0.zip). I just googled the name of the `.zip` file, `SynCOMAPIv1_0`, and found [this](http://hackipedia.org/Platform/x86/PS2%20mouse,%20synaptics/zip,%20synaptics%20API%20and%20example/SynCOMAPIv1_0.zip) working download link. But, when I open the help file, `SynCOMAPIv1_0.zip/Help/SynSDK.chm`, I get tons of `Navigation to the webpage was canceled` errors, so I have no clue how to install the SDK so that I can [use it with c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16442480/synaptics-touchpad-signature). Please, help me figure out how to install it for use with `Visual Studio C#`.

Comment: [Solution to your .cHM errors here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jpsanders/2009/06/10/some-chm-files-do-not-work-on-windows-7-process-monitor-navigation-to-the-webpage-was-canceled/)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I just went to properties, and unblocked the `.chm` file. It has an explanation under `Synaptics SDK>Installation>Installing the SDK`